# Fundamental group of $\Bbb C^2$ minus three lines passing through the origin

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $L_i$ ($i=1,2,3$) be three different lines passing through $0 \in \mathbb C^2$, and $D = \bigcup_i L_i$. What is $\pi_1(\mathbb C ^2 \setminus D)$ ?

Remark : I think if the three lines intersects each other at different points, then we have $\pi_1(\mathbb C ^2 \setminus D) = \mathbb Z^3$. Also the group we are looking for is not abelian.

What I tried : this space is a fiber bundle over $\mathbb C \setminus \{ 0,1\}$ with fiber $\mathbb C^*$. Alternatively, it's a fiber bundle over $\mathbb C^*$ with fiber $\mathbb C \setminus \{0,1\}$. We get a short exact sequence $\{e\} \to \mathbb Z \to \pi_1(\mathbb C^2 \setminus D) \to \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \{e\}$. But I don't know if it's split or not.

Actually, it's also possible to retract this space on $S^3$ minus three circles, but it's unclear how to use it. Also Van Kampen doesn't seems to work here.

Comment: Notice how I edited this question. The symbol $\cup$ is used for $A\cup B$ and $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$ and the like. The symbol $\bigcup$ is used for things like $\bigcup_i L_i.$ And $\mathbb C^2\backslash D$ looks different from $\mathbb C^2\setminus D$ for a good reason.  Likewise $\mathbb Z*\mathbb Z$ differs from $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z. \qquad$

Comment: Isn't your space simply (homeomorphic to) the _product_ $(\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}) \times (\mathbb C\setminus \{0,1\})$? No need to call it a fiber bundle and need to worry about how the fibers join up globally.

Comment: @Troposphere : Could you write an explicit homeomorphism please ?

Comment: $(z,w)\mapsto (z,w/z): \{(z,w)\mid z\ne 0, w\ne 0, z\ne w\} \to (\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}) \times (\mathbb C\setminus\{0,1\})$

Comment: Are those real lines or complex lines?